# method overloading with QString or std::string : call is ambiguous

Tags: qt, stdstring, ambiguous-call

I have a class which looks like this :

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void drawText(const QString& rText);
    void drawText(const std::string& rText);
};
```

I overloaded the `drawText()` method because I want to accept `QString` as well as `std::string`.

But when I write something like this :

```
MyClass foo;
foo.drawText("Hello");
```

The compiler is complaining that the call to `drawText()` is ambiguous.

I understand that from an array of char, the compiler cannot decide between a `QString` or a `std::string`, because both provide a suitable constructor.

But is there a way for me to make sure the user can use the `drawText()` method either by passing a `QString` or a `std::string`or an array of char ?

Comment: You are using QT why not use only the QString and stay out of the std functionality? Combining 2 libraries with similar functionality is going to bite you in the ass later on.

Comment: I'm usually using only QString and I could stick with it, but my question is more because of curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yes: add another overload which takes `const char*`

The implicit conversion from `const char*` to QString is problematic because it assumes that the input is ASCII.  I suspect the Qt folks would like to remove that constructor altogether but it would break source compatibility.  If you want to disable it in your app, you can define QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII.